# Giant Glory size

Tags: downhill

Hi my friend found an Giant Glory 2 2013 large for a good price. He is 180cm tall and the recommendation for the bike is 185cm+ so my question is will he be able to ride it or will it be too big?

Comment: He should try it in the store. Keep in mind that a bike purchased for a song, that the user doesn't ride because it's uncomfortable, isn't really a bargain at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

Even if someone has a particular height, inseam, and other measurements and compares it to a chart the manufacturer makes, its not necessarily a good bike for them or not. They have to try the bike and see if it fits them well or not. Some people like bigger bikes for a given height, others will like smaller bikes.